# How to clear previous commands before showing the result of :!command on VIM?

Tags: vim

For example, if you use the following command on VIM:

```
:!ls
```

It will show the contents of the folder (as expected) plus the result of your previous commands. I want it to show only the last result. How?

Comment: I don't reproduce what you say. Typing `!ls` only shows the result of that command to me. I'm using MacVim 7.4-snapshot72.

Comment: I'm using normal VIM on Mac...

Comment: I can reproduce it now. Problem shows up when using OSX's default vim, or MacVim in terminal mode, but it doesn't when using MacVim in  GUI mode. So, this seems a difference between terminal and GUI mode. I've been searching for a while but haven't discovered why.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
:!clear && ls
```